# $resource URL data issue

Tags: angularjs

From where the data is coming/posted in following code given in angular tutorial.I tried the same using json file but data is not getting posted or updated in json file .

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
 {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
 charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
 });

// We can retrieve a collection from the server
var cards = CreditCard.query(function() {
// GET: /user/123/card
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to $resource() is the url where the data is coming from (for GET) or posted (for POST). Parts of the url not supplied will default to the current page url, so for example if the page using this code is at http://example.com:8080/somepath/example.html then this resource would be getting data from http://example.com:8080/user/123/card/456 (or whatever @id is).

Comment: what does /123/card/456  this imply ? is it some folder ?

Comment: 123 is just an example userId and 456 is an example cardId. This url structure is common for REST requests. They are usually not actual folders.